# Push from cloned TFS Git repo to the origin

Tags: git

I've cloned a Git repository from an external Git server (it's a corporate Github) to my TFS 2017. I then made some commits in that repo in TFS. How can I now push those commits back into the external Git server?

EDIT: looks like this all hinges on the ability to add an external repo. Local git repo would let you create one, the git within TFS won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a local repo that's synced to the TFS repo.

Add the external git server as a second remote:

```
git remote add external https://external.remote.url/
```

Then push your commits out to the remote:

```
git push external branch-to-push
```

You can do the same thing from Visual Studio by going to Settings in Team Explorer, choose the repository settings and add the remote:

[image]

Then go to the sync tab and Push to the external remote by choosing it from the extended <kbd>push | v</kbd> option:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant, like designating a remote in TFS, or designating the TFS as a remote for the external server (it's a corporate Github). But this will do in a pinch :)

Comment: There may be a way for the remote servers. To fetch/pull directly from TFS, but TFS has no features to do this by itself

Comment: Made a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144968/remote-repository-on-github That one is really about Guthub UI/API, not about git proper.