# Designate a non-Github repo as a remote on Github

Tags: git, github

I'd like to sync a repository between a corporate Github and a corporate TFS. TFS UI don't support remote repositories on the server.

Is there a way to designate the git repo within TFS as a remote on Github? I know I can sync via a local repo that would list both as remotes, but can this be done without a local one?

Comment: Which tfs version? Tfs 2017 offers basic Auth access using access tokens over SSL, older versions require NTLM.or Kerberos.

Comment: TFS 2017 update 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't such an official tool or services. You have to manually do the sync via a local repo as you mentioned.

> If you are using a Git repository in TFS then you can create set up
>   two remotes in a local Git repository, i.e
>
> ```
> git remote add upstream https://github.com/foo/bar.git
> git remote add origin https://tfsserver/DefaultCollection/_git/bar
> ```
>
> And then simply do a `git pull` upstream master followed by a `git push`
>   origin master assuming that master is the branch that you want to keep
>   in sync.
>
> With either version control system, you probably want to keep a branch
>   in version control in your TFS repository to match what is in your
>   upstream GitHub project so that you can easily see change coming in
>   the one place and then handle your merges inside your local
>   repository.
>
> *Source Link:
>   [Integrating Github code to TFS - auto check-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380169/integrating-github-code-to-tfs-auto-check-in)*

Another workaround is with help of a special build in TFS, then calling git command during the build pipeline. Detail steps please refer this blog: [Keep Git repository in sync between VSTS / TFS and Git](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/10/22/keep-git-repository-in-sync-between-vsts-tfs-and-git/).  You could also use the [Git Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.gittasks) in marketplace.

Also reference this article : [Sync between my GitHub and Visual Studio Online](http://mohamedradwan.com/2015/10/11/sync-between-my-github-and-visual-studio-online/)

You can also submit a user voice to suggest the feature on this site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services